# How do i get the phantom prospect dog tag?

Tags: battlefield-4

I am trying to get the phantom prospect dog tag and i am stuck on the "Get a total of 300 meter headshot". Do I have to get all of the head shots in one match or can it be spread out?

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of the other one about this.

Comment: @MarkRogers Yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this video about *Phantom Prospect* assignment:

There it literally says:

> Get a 300 meter headshot

My interpretation of this would be:

*Make a (single) headshot of 300+ meters*

To be honest, 300 meter is super close in terms of sniper shooting. Try playing on some big map with many players(to make sure there are enough people running around/sniping) as a recon. A good example would be *Operation Firestorm* where you often have snipers on the mountains. And snipers are normally a non-moving target making it very easy to headshot them(unless they headshot you of course)